# How can i configure javascript indentation on sublime text 2

Tags: comments, sublimetext2, auto-indent

when i use reindent function with sublime text 2, my javascript code indent according to last comment line, like this :

before reindent :

```
function a_function() {
some_code()
// some comment
some_code_again();
}
```

after reindent :

```
function a_function() {
    some_code()
// some comment
some_code_again();
}
```

Someone know how can i configure indent function for comment too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found another solution.
I use package JsFormat on sublime text